# WP display all custom fields with same key?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using custom field on custom post types.

To display value of single custom field I use this code:

```
$gym_title = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cast', true); 

echo $gym_title;
```

Is there a way to display all custom fields with key ="gym" ?

(I have tried to use foreach and  to write custom database search but no luck for now.)

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query

Comment: Thank You both for contributing with Your answers.
I have used Ismail code and adopt it a little bit and now it is working fine on my website. I have added my own table name, row name, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example function which queries the database for all posts and returns all custom fields with a specific key:

```
function get_all_custom_fields( $key ) {

    global $wpdb;

    $r = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
        SELECT pm.meta_value FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} pm
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} p ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        WHERE pm.meta_key = '%s'
    ", $key) );

    return $r;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
$gym_titles = get_all_custom_fields('gym');
```